# Blazorise button styles not showing in Server side Bazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I have just started looking at [Blazorise](https://blazorise.com/). The project is .NET Core 3.1 with server side blazor.  Blazorise installed via NuGet at v0.9.1.2.

I have a Blazorise grid functionally working well, now I added a button to the top of the form - simply

```
<Button Color="Color.Danger">Test</Button>
```

and the button appears but without color/styling.  I have installed and setup as per the documentation.  All CSS & JavaScript is being referenced by the page (verified in view source).
I have Blazorise in my `_imports.razor` file. I have the documented entries in `Startup.cs`.

Any ideas as what might be missed?

Comment: It seems that the styling is picked up if I change <Button> to <Blazorise.Bootstrap.Button> as both namespaces have 'Button'.  There must be a way of cleanly defining the Bootstrap version is required.

Comment: You need post your code.

Comment: Fixed as I was preparing to add code.  The magic of coming back fresh the next day.  Not sure if it was an extra using statement causing the issue.  On a positive note Blazorise looks like a very nicely put together project.

Comment: delete folder `bin` and `obj`